# The entity (function results) in DomainService does not have a key defined

Tags: sql-function, domainservices

In the project I am working currently, there are many table-valued functions within Meter.dbml. For a week ago, I had no problem working with these function. But after I got new working laptop and checked out the project using Tortoise SVN, the following error occured:

> "The entity '(function result name)' in DomainService '(Domain service name)' does not have a key defined. Entities exposed by DomainService operations must have at least one public property marked with the KeyAttribute."

I don't want to remove these functions from dbml because they are used in many classes.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have found the solution. The main reason for this error is that I forgot to install Visual Studio 2010 Service pack 1. After knowing that, I download service pack from this link:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691

After finish installing, I removed references related to domain service, which I manually added from dll file I copied from my old computer. Then I searched and added these references from .NET Component instead. Now it works without any error.